# Running docker exec command with a shell string and parameters in bash script

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to run the following docker exec command in a bash script where I'm passing 2 parameters into the bash script.  The command is supposed to delete directories that begin with a certain string.  I don't seem to be passing in the parameters correctly:

- $container is set to $1
- $database is set to $2
- $currdate is set internally in the bash script

  docker exec $container sh -c 'rm -rf /path/to/directory/${database}-${currdate}-*/'

Comment: 1.  use your variables inside double-quotes. 2. variables inside single quotes do not interpolate. hope it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use double quotes to interpolate variables. Single quotes won't interpolate anything, but double quotes will.

```
docker exec $container sh -c "rm -rf /path/to/directory/${database}-${currdate}-*/"
```

From Bash manual:

> [3.1.2.2 Single Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)

Enclosing characters in single quotes (`'`) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

> [3.1.2.3 Double Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes (`"`) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, and, when history expansion is enabled, `!`. The characters `$` and `` ` `` retain their special meaning within double quotes (see [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions)). The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: `$`, `` ` ``, `"`, `\`, or newline. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an `!` appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the `!` is not removed.

The special parameters `*` and `@` have special meaning when in double quotes (see [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)).